# Styling text by outputted document.write

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a login php form, when the user types the incorrect credentials then it will output "Incorrect Username or Password" however this is put right at the top of the website above the navigation. Here is a screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiHf5.jpg

I would like to have the text placed inside the website wrapper and within a div so that i can edit it with css.

I have tried using `document.getElementById('log').innerHTML` however this only works when the div "log" is above the php code, however the php has to stay at the top because otherwise I get a error:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent

Here is my php/js

In short, all i would like to do is when the login credentials are wrong a message is shown to the user "Incorrect Username or Password" This message i need to be editable with CSS, as i need to reposition it on the page. 
If anybody would please be able to edit my code and explain to me what they have done - it would be hugely appreciated.

Here is my PHP with JS:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
 header("Location: account.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
 if($row['password']==md5($upass))
 {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
  header("Location: account.php");
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <script>document.write('Incorrect Username or Password');</script>
        <?php
 }

}
?>
```

Here is my HTML

```
<?php include"authentication/login.php";?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<HEAD>
<title>Website | Loign</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php include "includes/page_sources.php"; ?>

</HEAD>
<body>


<?php include "includes/navigation.php"; ?> 

<div id="wrapper">



<div id="login-form">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required />
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Your Password" required />
        <button type="submit" name="btn-login">Log In</button>
        <a href="register.php">Sign Up</a>
    </form>
</div>



</div>

<?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Thank you once again for any help in advance

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant to this question. We need the rendered HTML and CSS.

Comment: You need a image of the website do you mean ? or shall i add the CSS code of the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's all kinds of wrong in your example. It doesn't matter where yo put your PHP code: if you want to append something to some sort of a div - then delay that until the dom loads. You'd be better off using jquery or something that had a "domReady" function available, but you can do without it as well. Instead of your document.write script you could just say:

```
window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('something').innerHTML = 'some html'; };
```

The above line would wait for the document to be loaded and it would now be able to find the div even if php code is above everything else.

Answer (score 1):

It is really very easy do it in this way

**PHP File:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$error="no";
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
 header("Location: account.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
 if($row['password']==md5($upass))
 {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
  header("Location: account.php");
 }
 else
 {
 $error="yes";
 }

}
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <?php include"authentication/login.php";?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <HEAD>
    <title>Website | Loign</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?php include "includes/page_sources.php"; ?>

    </HEAD>
    <body>


    <?php include "includes/navigation.php"; ?> 

    <div id="wrapper">



    <div id="login-form">
        <form method="post">
<?php if($error=="yes") echo 'Incorrect Username or Password';?>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required />
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Your Password" required />
            <button type="submit" name="btn-login">Log In</button>
            <a href="register.php">Sign Up</a>
        </form>
    </div>



    </div>

    <?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```